# Go: Modelling general JSON arrays in a struct possible?

Tags: json, struct, go

I want to be able to Marshal/Unmarshall a struct

```
type MyType struct {
    Items    <What goes here?>   `json:"item"`
}
```

Where an example JSON document it must be able to handle is

```
{"items":["value1", {"x":"y"}, "value3"]}
```

I am only starting to learn Go.  I am starting to think I might need to impose some restrictions on the structure of the array.  Using the above example, my idea would be

```
{"items":[
    {"type":null, "value":"value1"}
    {"type:"x", "value":"y"},
    {"type": "value3", "value":"value3"}
]}
```

Then modelling the objects inside with their own struct.  I'd rather do it the first way, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Items have to be an array of interface

like this:

```
Items []interface{}
```

here is a complete example:
http://play.golang.org/p/LOXCiSmUET

when you unmarshal your json, and want to iterate over your Items you need to identify the type. when doing be aware that complex types are represented as  **map[string]interface** and not as struct, in such case your need to create the struct by your self